# Interaction between parser and telegram bot

Tags: python, api, python-requests, bots, telegram

I wrote a parser that collects air quality data from the resource https://www.iqair.com
and I want to configure its interaction with the telegram bot.
I do not want a request to the site to be sent for each request of the telegram bot user. How can you send a request every 30 minutes, save it somewhere, and, at the request of the user, pass it on to him? So that it all works on the server, at the same time

Comment: There are multiple questions with multiple possible answers each. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych,  I'm interested in any answers, because I don't know what features can be used here

Comment: you don't need any special modules or functions for this - you need only check time. Keep data in global variable or in file or database. Keep in global variable time when you run last request and compare it with current time when you have to run next request - if difference is lower then 30 minut then get data from variable/file/database and display this data. If difference is bigger then 30 minut then run request, keep new  data in variable/file/database, keep new time in variable, and display this data.

Comment: I'm not sure which bot (`telergram` or `discord`) can use function `task(seconds=...)` to execute function periodically - and this function could run every 30 minut and run request and keep data in global variable or file/database. And when user ask for data then it should display data from global variable or file/database.

Comment: i'm not sure but module `requests` may have other module (probably `requests-cache`) which can cache responses in database SQLite with time how long data are coorect - and when you run request then it checks this time and gets data from database or runs real request

Comment: [requests-cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)